# Memory management in Go

Tags: go

I have a closure where I declare and define local variables:

```
func writer_factory() func() *net.TCPConn {

    response_port := "localhost:8000"
    tcpAddr_res, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", response_port)
    checkError(err)
    var response_writer *net.TCPConn
    checkError(err)
    return func() *net.TCPConn {
        if response_writer == nil{
            response_writer, err = net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr_res)
            checkError(err)
        }
        return response_writer
    }
}
```

Now my question is, if I call this `writer_factory` multiple times will I get a memory leak?

So specifically, will I have a memory leak using `writer_factory` in this program:

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
//  "io/ioutil"


)

//fmt.Printf("messages are (1) %q\n", messages)

func main() {

    end_of_message_terminator := "||"
    beginning_of_next_message := ""
    request := make([]byte, 512)

    service_port := ":7777"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", service_port)
    checkError(err)
    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)



    for {
        response_writer := writer_factory()

        conn, err := listener.Accept()

        if err != nil {

            continue

        }

        read_len, err := conn.Read(request)

        if read_len == 0 {
            continue
        }

        request_string := string(request[:read_len])


        messages := strings.Split(request_string, end_of_message_terminator)


        messages[0] = beginning_of_next_message + messages[0]

        if messages[len(messages) - 1] != "" {
            beginning_of_next_message = messages[len(messages) - 1]
            messages[len(messages) - 1] = ""

        }

        if len(messages) == 1 {
            continue
        }

        rw := response_writer()
        join_channel := make(chan struct{})
        for i := 0; i < len(messages); i++ {


            go func(i int, rw  *net.TCPConn){

                respond_to_message(messages[i], rw)
                join_channel <- struct{}{}

            }(i, rw)


        }

        go func (){

            for i := 0; i < len(messages); i++ {

                <- join_channel

            }


            rw.Close()

        }()
        conn.Close()


    }

}


func writer_factory() func() *net.TCPConn {

    response_port := "localhost:8000"
    tcpAddr_res, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", response_port)
    checkError(err)
    var response_writer *net.TCPConn
    checkError(err)
    return func() *net.TCPConn {
        if response_writer == nil{
            response_writer, err = net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr_res)
            checkError(err)
        }
        return response_writer
    }
}


func respond_to_message(message string, response_writer *net.TCPConn){

    message_parameters := strings.Split(message, "|")

    //response_writer.Write([]byte("asti de chris"))
    for i := range message_parameters {




        param_parts := strings.Split(message_parameters[i], "=")

        param_name := param_parts[0]

        //param_value := param_parts[1]


        response_writer.Write([]byte(param_name))

        //fmt.Println(string(result))




    }


}


func checkError(err error) {

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)

    }

}
```

To exercise this code launch the program, then launch this program `netcat -l -p 8000` and then this program `printf "asti||"  | netcat localhost 7777`

Comment: Very few things in Go have the potential to cause memory leaks (`time.Tick` is the only thing that comes to mind at the moment). If you cannot access a value (i.e. its reference is gone), it will garbage collected sometime in the future.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to close a TCPConn or you'll get, if not a memory leak, at least a file pointer leak.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely improve performance by using one connection or (if one connection is not thread save) use a `sync.Pool`. That would save you memory allocations (and with it garbage collection) and also time wasted on opening all those tcp connections.

Comment: but I do close it no? Like this: `go func (){

            for i := 0; i < len(messages); i++ {

                <- join_channel

            }


            rw.Close()

        }()`

Comment: Sorry. Don't know if it is wise to leave connections open when you put them back in the sync pool. Maybe someone else knows?